# CPU1 failed to come online

Tags: c, linux-kernel, smp

Could someone explain why we get the message below in kernel in SMP environment?

> CPU1 failed to come online

Source kernel_msm-4.9/kernel/arch/arm/kernel/smp.c:

```
if (!cpu_online(cpu)) 
{
    pr_crit("CPU%u: failed to come online\n", cpu);
    ret = -EIO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that CPU `1` is set offline in the system to not schedule, receive interrupts form the devices. Below we can see 4 cores are available, and when one of the core is disabled using sysfs option it became offline.

```
[root@ucc1 bin]# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online 
0-3

[root@ucc1 bin]# echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/online
[root@ucc1 bin]# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/online
0-2

[root@ucc1 bin]# cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/offline
3
```